# Understanding Recursion on Tree Traversals

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand how recursion works and how traversing a Binary Tree works.

Okay so from what I know, recursion is calling a function within it self. Kind of like looping.

Now I was given the code on how to do a **postOrder** traversal on a Binary Tree.

(Note this is not my code, I am just trying to understand how recursion works through this code)

```
 # Definition for a  binary tree node
 # class TreeNode:
 #     def __init__(self, x):
 #         self.val = x
 #         self.left = None
 #         self.right = None

 class Solution:
     # @param root, a tree node
     # @return a list of integers

 def postorderTraversal(self, root):
    solution = []
    self.postorderTraversalRec(root, solution)
    return solution

 def postorderTraversalRec(self, root, solution):
    if root == None:
        return
    self.postorderTraversalRec(root.left, solution)
    self.postorderTraversalRec(root.right, solution)
    solution.append(root.val)
```

Now from what I understand a **PostOrder** traversal goes **right-left-middle** so child first then parent.

Here are the 2 lines where I think recursion is taking place.

```
    self.postorderTraversalRec(root.left, solution)
    self.postorderTraversalRec(root.right, solution)
```

From what I can understand is that the first line tells the program to recursively go through all the left nodes till it reaches the end. Then it tell the program to go through all the left hand nodes till it reaches the end.

But the problem I am facing is that, I cannot understand how this does a **PostOrder** traversal. To me it looks like a **PreOrder** traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Post-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) is as follows:

1. Traverse the left subtree.
2. Traverse the right subtree.
3. Visit the root.

Which is exactly what is happening here. For any given node (`root`), first you visit the left sub-tree (`root.left`), then the right sub-tree (`root.right`), then node itself (`root.val`).

The "pre" or "post" part of the traversal-type refers to when the value of the current node is visited, either before visiting the child nodes (pre-), after (post-), or even between visiting each child node (in-order traversal). In your example code the current node's value is visited after traversing the children. So, it's post-order traversal.

Comment: I am confused.. that when we call the recursive function:     self.postorderTraversalRec(root.left, solution) .. it continues to recursivly go through all left nodes... and once all left nodes end.. it goes through the right hand nodes... That is my thinking.

Comment: @Ali Yep, that's exactly what it does. You're still describing post-order traversal.

Comment: but how is that different from preorder?

Comment: @Ali for pre-order, we start by traversing the root first. Check this link to understand tree Traversal algorithms visually. http://www.algomation.com/algorithm/tree-traversal-preorder-inorder-postorder-breadth-first

Comment: In pre-order, we would append the `root.val` before recursing instead of after.

Comment: @Ali: Your function will look like: In case of Pre-order recursion:  def preorderTraversalRec(self, root, solution):
    if root == None:
        return
    solution.append(root.val)  self.preorderTraversalRec(root.left, solution)
    self.preorderTraversalRec(root.right, solution)

Comment: yes thank you sir ! I am getting an understanding of how these two pre and post traversals are different.