# Understanding Recursion in Tree Traversal

Tags: python, recursion

This question may be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569349/understanding-recursion-on-tree-traversals) but there is slight nuance. I would like to understand how the recursion works when there are two recursion calls one underneath the other.

Consider the following tree traversal for preorder.

[image]. [Ref: educative.io]

I have added few print statement to understand how each recursion call is working:

```
from Node import Node
from BinarySearchTree import BinarySearchTree


def preOrderPrint(node):
    if node is not None:
        print(node.val)
        preOrderPrint(node.leftChild)
        print('Done with left node')
        preOrderPrint(node.rightChild) 
        print('Done with right node')


BST = BinarySearchTree(6)
BST.insert(4)
BST.insert(9)
BST.insert(5)
BST.insert(2)
BST.insert(8)
BST.insert(12)

preOrderPrint(BST.root)
```

The output is the following:

```
6
4
2
Done with left node
Done with right node
Done with left node
5
Done with left node
Done with right node
Done with right node
Done with left node
9
8
Done with left node
Done with right node
Done with left node
12
Done with left node
Done with right node
Done with right node
Done with right node
```

Here's my understanding and the question:

So, the base case is that the recursion terminates when the node is None. The recursion for the left happens first and prints out the node as it goes down the tree. Once it hits the left node of 2, it terminates. This is shown in the print state of "Done with left node".

The recursion for the right takes over. The last node visited is 2 so it starts from there. It terminates because right child of 2 is None. This is shown in the print statement of "Done with right node".

Now, the right recursion goes up to 4. **Question: Why does the code print "Done with left node" before printing 5 and not print 2 again?** How does it know that left node has been done? Can you explain in terms of stacks, that the recursion uses? Or any other way.

Comment: It's printing that the left node of node `4` (i.e. the node `2`) has been completed, before entering the right node of node `4` (i.e. the node `5`).

Comment: I'd consider `if node.leftChild: print('Done with left child of', node.val) else: print('No left child of', node.val)`. Ditto right.

Comment: The recursive call frames wait until their child calls complete before resuming execution and eventually returning. In terms of stacks, the child call is pushed, eventually pops, and then the parent can pop. The parent has already printed 2 and can't be re-visited--execution within each frame is top-to-bottom as normal. I recommend adding indentation to your prints to help visualize, as the dupe suggestion indicates (you can plug your tree structure into that visualizer). Picture a degenerate tree as a linked list, you'd see the call stack expand, then everything pop one by one.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827894/recursion-with-code-after-the-recursive-call/51828267#51828267) another one that might help--it may not look the same, but it is--two calls per frame and basically traverses a perfect tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like my comment suggests, you're not only printing "done with ..." for leaf nodes; instead you're doing that for every node in the tree, even intermediary ones.

I suggest changing your function as follows in order to see this more clearly:

```
def preOrderPrint(node):
    if node is not None:
        print(node.val)
        preOrderPrint(node.leftChild)
        print('Done with left node of node', node.val)
        preOrderPrint(node.rightChild) 
        print('Done with right node of node', node.val)
```

your output should now be:

```
6
4
2
Done with left node of node 2
Done with right node of node 2
Done with left node of node 4
5
...
```

Comment: How does the recursion know it has been done with left node of node 4? That's confusing for me.

Comment: @Rohit because the child call `return`s control to the parent and the `print('Done with left node')` for the parent call can execute.

Comment: Because your program instructs to print `"Done with left node of node 4"` immediately after entering `4`'s left node. So once the program returns from the recursive calls related to `4`'s left node (however many that may be), it will print exactly that.

Comment: Your explanation along with a suggested link to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63962871/understanding-printed-output-for-a-bst-traversal was very helpful!